# Finding the minimal radius of body in elliptic motion

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, angular-momentum, potential-energy

Assume I have a body with mass $m$ with particular velocity $v_0$, that is is being pulled by a radial force which is linearly proportional to the radius $r$, which is the body's distance from the source of the force. That is, the more distant the body from the source of the force, the stronger the radial force becomes. Let's assume we know $r_0$.

Now, let's say that the body has angular momentum $J \neq 0$ according to the source of the force, so that means that the velocity is not colinear with the force.

How can I find the minimal radius possible in the movement?

Answer (score 0):

You use energy and angular momentum conservation. Find these quantities at the initial point, and then observe that at perihelion $\dot r=0$.